# incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Values'

Tags: asp.net

this is my code.i want to save these values into database.And an error occured,

> incorrect syntax near the keyword Values

```
foreach (GridViewRow gvr in GridView1.Rows)
{
string strcon1;
strcon1 = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["fwma_devConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(strcon1);
con1.Open();
SqlCommand com3 = new SqlCommand(strcon);
TextBox tb = (TextBox)gvr.FindControl("TextBox2");//value
string txt = tb.Text;

Label propertylabel = (Label)gvr.FindControl("Label4");//id-property

com3.CommandText = "INSERT INTO BrandProperties(PropertyID,BrandID,Values) values(" + propertylabel.Text + "," + B_id.Text + "," + tb.Text + " ), con1";
com3.Connection = con1;
com3.ExecuteNonQuery();
con1.Close();
```

Comment: Bracket Values in the insert column list, ie `,[Values]) `

Comment: Shouldn't you have ' around the text properties? Eg. `('" + propertylabel.Text + "',")`

Comment: @alexw Oh good catch, he's missing that for all the columns.

Comment: @alexw: corrected but same error occured

Comment: @ASAWYER & ALEXW :THANKU.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the [reserved keywords](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx) ,you should specify delimited identifiers either quoted or bracketed.

**example using bracketed**

```
com3.CommandText = "INSERT INTO BrandProperties(PropertyID,BrandID,[Values]) values(" + propertylabel.Text + "," + B_id.Text + "," + tb.Text + " ), con1";
```

Answer (score 3):

use this

```
com3.CommandText = "INSERT INTO BrandProperties(PropertyID,BrandID,Values) values('" + propertylabel.Text + "','" + B_id.Text + "','" + tb.Text + "')";
```

instead of

```
com3.CommandText = "INSERT INTO BrandProperties(PropertyID,BrandID,Values) values(" + propertylabel.Text + "," + B_id.Text + "," + tb.Text + " ), con1";
```

Comment: Try now, If your column is string type

Comment: What error ? Can you run SQL Command in SQL Query, to find out the exact problem.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't this line be like this?

```
        com3.CommandText = "INSERT INTO BrandProperties(PropertyID,BrandID,Values) values(" + propertylabel.Text + "," + B_id.Text + "," + tb.Text + ")";
```

and please use command parameters:

[When should "SqlDbType" and "size" be used when adding SqlCommand Parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624811/different-ways-of-passing-sqlcommand-parameters)