# Pass arguments from C# objects to SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2012

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace iss_farmacie_spitali
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            sqlConnection1.Open();
            sqlCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("user",textBox1.Text);
            sqlCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("pass",textBox2.Text);
            sqlCommand1.CommandText = "SELECT id,parola FROM ANGAJAT WHERE id=(user) AND    parola=(pass)";
            if (sqlCommand1.ExecuteNonQuery()!=null)
                MessageBox.Show("ESTE");
            sqlConnection1.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

What I hope to accomplish is build a functional login. I have the database, a table named "angajati"(employees) containing id(a username practically) and parola(which is password). What I want to know it I can introduce "variables" within the SQL script text to have it run like a function and simply pass the values from my text boxes. This is what I made up from other examples but it doesn't seem to work. Could anybody give me a bit of insight upon the matter?

Comment: I think perhaps you should look here for the answer you seek: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624811/different-ways-of-passing-sqlcommand-parameters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            sqlConnection1.Open();
            sqlCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user",textBox1.Text);
            sqlCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass",textBox2.Text);
            sqlCommand1.CommandText = "SELECT id,parola FROM ANGAJAT WHERE id='@user' AND    parola='@pass'";
            if (sqlCommand1.ExecuteNonQuery()!=null)
                MessageBox.Show("ESTE");
            sqlConnection1.Close();
        }
```

Comment: You don't need quotes around the parameters in the SQL.