# Visual Basic can't convert to (MySQL)bit type

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to insert values from form to my database. In table I have declared Zavrseno as bit type. I fetch Zavrseno value from check box as boolean type in form. When I execute query I get error:"Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ' True ' to data type bit."

```
    Dim t1 As DateTime = Me.VrijemePocetkaDateTimePicker.Text
    Dim t2 As String = Me.Tim1TextBox.Text
    Dim t3 As String = Me.Tim2TextBox.Text
    Dim t4 As Boolean = Me.ZavrsenoCheckBox.Checked

    cmd = New SqlCommand("insert into   dbo.Utakmice(VrijemePocetka,Tim1,Tim2,Zavrseno) values(' " & t1 & " ', ' " & t2 & " ' ,' " & t3 & " ' ,' " & t4 &" ')", conn)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is [`Boolean.ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/atahsch6.aspx) results in "True" or "False" which are *invalid values* for a BIT (or integer) field - BIT values should be 0 or 1 (or coercible to such).

To fix this, [**use parameters**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624811/different-ways-of-passing-sqlcommand-parameters). 
 Using parameters will clean up the query, prevent SQL injection<sup>1</sup>, *and* make the code "just work".

---

<sup>1</sup> SQL injection doesn't have to be malicious: the program will break as written if the user enters `'` into one of the text fields.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this. Can you give example on my code , how it should look?