# SQL replace two records while cloning a row

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have coded this snippet to clone a selected row in a table:

```
protected void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime ucode = DateTime.Now;
    string slctedProj = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString();
    string new_code = "PR" + ucode.ToString("ssmmHHddMM");

    string query = @"INSERT INTO Projects (proj_id, proj_prod_id, proj_cust_id, proj_man_id,
                    proj_name, proj_date, proj_num_of_vehicles, proj_coach_vehicle,
                    proj_contract_value, proj_length, proj_width, proj_height, proj_passenger_seats,
                    proj_passenger_total, proj_type, proj_notes, uname, proj_brand, proj_systemvoltage,
                    proj_gauge, proj_service_speed)
                    SELECT proj_id, proj_prod_id, proj_cust_id, proj_man_id,
                    proj_name, proj_date, proj_num_of_vehicles, proj_coach_vehicle,
                    proj_contract_value, proj_length, proj_width, proj_height, proj_passenger_seats,
                    proj_passenger_total, proj_type, proj_notes, uname, proj_brand, proj_systemvoltage,
                    proj_gauge, proj_service_speed
                    FROM Projects WHERE proj_name =" + "'" + slctedProj + "'";
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(query);
    string getconnstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["stad_conn"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(getconnstring);
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}
```

the code is working fine but I need to replace in the new row, "proj_id" with the string "new_code" and attach at the beginning of the "proj_name" something like "Cloned".
How can I do that?

Comment: Just change your `SELECT` query to include those values.

Comment: @SLaks, thanks but that is exactly my problem.I do not know how to change it. I do not use sql often.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all:  [Use parameters in your SQL command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/using-parameters-in-sql-statements).

Heres the revised code, with parameters.  Note that the Add method on the parameters is specifying both the data type as well as the length.  [It's better to specify these explicitly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624811/different-ways-of-passing-sqlcommand-parameters) rather than let ADO.Net assume it knows what you want.

```
DateTime ucode = DateTime.Now;
string slctedProj = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString();
string new_code = "PR" + ucode.ToString("ssmmHHddMM");
string new_projectName = "Some new name";

string query = @"INSERT INTO Projects (proj_id, proj_prod_id, proj_cust_id, proj_man_id,
                proj_name, proj_date, proj_num_of_vehicles, proj_coach_vehicle,
                proj_contract_value, proj_length, proj_width, proj_height, proj_passenger_seats,
                proj_passenger_total, proj_type, proj_notes, uname, proj_brand, proj_systemvoltage,
                proj_gauge, proj_service_speed)
                SELECT @NewProjectID, proj_prod_id, proj_cust_id, proj_man_id,
                @NewProjectName, proj_date, proj_num_of_vehicles, proj_coach_vehicle,
                proj_contract_value, proj_length, proj_width, proj_height, proj_passenger_seats,
                proj_passenger_total, proj_type, proj_notes, uname, proj_brand, proj_systemvoltage,
                proj_gauge, proj_service_speed
                FROM Projects WHERE proj_name = @SelectedProj";

System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(query);

string getconnstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["stad_conn"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(getconnstring);
conn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@NewProjectID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = new_code;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@NewProjectName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = new_projectName;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@SelectedProj", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = slctedProj;

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer. You could improve this design by keeping a reference to source / initial project using a FK (only for cloned projects) thus:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Projects
ADD source_proj_id INT NULL
REFERENCES dbo.Projects(proj_id);
GO
```

and you need to change also the insert statement thus:

```
string query = @"INSERT INTO Projects 
                (proj_id, source_proj_id, proj_prod_id, ...)
                SELECT @NewProjectID, proj_id, proj_prod_id, ...
                FROM Projects WHERE proj_name = @SelectedProj";
```