# I am having trouble inserting into my database with c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I get this error when trying to insert data into my database.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'User'.

Here is the code:

```
if(txtRegisterSecurityAnswerOne.TextLength >0 && txtRegisterSecurityAnswerTwo.TextLength >0)
{
    SqlConnection connection1 = new SqlConnection(
        Properties.Settings.Default.BlackBookDBConnectionString);

    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO User (Username, Password, SecurityQuestionOne, "
        + "SecurityQuestionTwo, SecurityAnswerOne, SecurityAnswerTwo); VALUES ("
        + txtRegisterUsername.Text + ","
        + txtRegisterPassword.Text + ","
        + lstRegisterSecurityQuestionOne.SelectedText + ","
        + lstRegisterSecurityQuestionTwo.SelectedItem + ","
        + txtRegisterSecurityAnswerOne.Text + ","
        + txtRegisterSecurityAnswerTwo.Text + ")";
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO USer ()";
    cmd.Connection = connection1;

    connection1.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    connection1.Close();
}
```

I have edited my code. However it still does not insert anything into my database for some reason.

```
if(txtRegisterSecurityAnswerOne.TextLength >0 && txtRegisterSecurityAnswerTwo.TextLength >0)
{
    SqlConnection connection1 = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.BlackBookDBConnectionString);

    string sqlquery = "INSERT INTO [User] (Username,Password,SecurityQuestionOne,"
        + "SecurityAnswerOne,SecurityQuestionTwo,SecurityAnswerTwo) "
        + "VALUES (@Username,@Password,@QuestionOne,@AnswerOne,@QuestionTwo,@AnswerTwo)";
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, connection1);

    string userName = txtRegisterUsername.Text;
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Username", userName);

    string password = txtRegisterRepeatPassword.Text;
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Password", password);

    string questionOne = lstRegisterSecurityQuestionOne.SelectedText;
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("QuestionOne", questionOne);

    string questionTwo = lstRegisterSecurityQuestionTwo.SelectedText;
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("QuestionTwo", questionTwo);

    string answerOne = txtRegisterSecurityAnswerOne.SelectedText;
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("AnswerOne", answerOne);

    string answerTwo = txtRegisterSecurityAnswerTwo.SelectedText;
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("AnswerTwo", answerTwo);

    command.Connection = connection1;

    connection1.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    connection1.Close();
}
```

Comment: *Use placeholders.* Lack of usage is the (or rather, one) *immediate* problem here (as the values are not quoted correctly), using them *will* avoid issues in the future - either accidental or malicious SQL injection.

Comment: You are begging for SQL Inject attacks.. Look into using Parameters for your inline queries. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624811/different-ways-of-passing-sqlcommand-parameters

Comment: What's your connection string?

Comment: SqlConnection connection1 = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.BlackBookDBConnectionString);
                            connection1.Open();

Comment: What does your connection string **look like?** (the content of it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(txtRegisterSecurityAnswerOne.TextLength >0 && txtRegisterSecurityAnswerTwo.TextLength >0)
{
    SqlConnection connection1 = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.BlackBookDBConnectionString);
    connection1.Open();
    string sqlquery = "INSERT INTO [User] (Username,Password,SecurityQuestionOne,"
        + "SecurityAnswerOne,SecurityQuestionTwo,SecurityAnswerTwo) "
        + "VALUES (@Username,@Password,@QuestionOne,@AnswerOne,@QuestionTwo,@AnswerTwo)";

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, connection1);

    string userName = txtRegisterUsername.Text;
    command.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200).Value = userName;
    string password = txtRegisterRepeatPassword.Text;
    command.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200).Value = password;
    string questionOne = lstRegisterSecurityQuestionOne.SelectedText;
    command.Parameters.Add("@QuestionOne", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200).Value = questionOne;
    string questionTwo = lstRegisterSecurityQuestionTwo.SelectedText;
    command.Parameters.Add("@QuestionTwo", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200).Value = questionTwo;
    string answerOne = txtRegisterSecurityAnswerOne.SelectedText;
    command.Parameters.Add("@AnswerOne", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200).Value = answerOne;
    string answerTwo = txtRegisterSecurityAnswerTwo.SelectedText;
    command.Parameters.Add("@AnswerTwo", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200).Value = answerTwo;

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    connection1.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove this line:

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO USer ()";
```

**EDIT**
After looking at your new code, you have wrong parameters names (missing `@`). You should change your code to this:

```
string userName = txtRegisterUsername.Text;
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", userName);

string password = txtRegisterRepeatPassword.Text;
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", password);

string questionOne = lstRegisterSecurityQuestionOne.SelectedText;
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QuestionOne", questionOne);

string questionTwo = lstRegisterSecurityQuestionTwo.SelectedText;
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QuestionTwo", questionTwo);

string answerOne = txtRegisterSecurityAnswerOne.SelectedText;
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AnswerOne", answerOne);

string answerTwo = txtRegisterSecurityAnswerTwo.SelectedText;
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AnswerTwo", answerTwo);
```

Comment: You don't need all the immediate local variables, but using placeholders is the way to go. I'd also include the updated SQL statement that uses such bindings.

Comment: Actually I did notice that however it is still not inserting.

Comment: Yes it is telling me invalid syntax near User

Comment: Nothing seems wrong with `sqlquery` in your new code, you have put square brackets there (`[User]`)

Answer (score 2):

1. Remove second line assigning `cmd.CommandText` - it's overwriting the first one
2. `User` is a keyword in SQL server, if you have a table with that name (which you should not) enclose it into square brackets:

   `cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [User] ...`

On a side note - learn about [parametrized queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). They're a great way to avois SQL injection attacks (not to mention confusing mess of string concatenation)

Comment: I have updated my code, can you take a look at it and see if you can find something wrong with it now?

Comment: @user3221702, if you read the link Yuriy provided you would see at least one thing wrong.