# Include textbox value in SQL Query

Tags: c#, sql, textbox, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to search a GridView using a textbox and search button. I think I need a query something like

```
SELECT employeeID, name, position, hourlyPayRate 
FROM dbo.employee 
WHERE name LIKE 'textBox1.text+'
```

I have made the query using the query designer in visual studio 2013.

I then have an event handler like this

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    this.employeeTableAdapter.FillBy(this.personnelDataSet.employee); 
}
```

I am sure that the problem is in the query but I just don't know how to include the value of the textbox into the query.

Comment: Why do people insist on using `DataTable` etc? Think of the kittens! Also: never ever concatenate input...

Comment: yes, very bad joo joo. Your uni lecturers deserve to be mocked. Leave the Jews alone, though ;p

Comment: haha I was just sounding it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To just change your query, it should look like:

```
string textboxValue = textbox1.Text;
string query = "SELECT employeeID, name, position, hourlyPayRate " +
               "FROM dbo.employee " +
               "WHERE name LIKE '" + textboxValue + "'";
```

But this is vulnerable to SQL injection, you should use a [**SqlCommand**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx) with [**parameters**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
string commandText = "SELECT employeeID, name, position, hourlyPayRate " +
                     "FROM dbo.employee WHERE name LIKE '%'+ @Name + '%'";

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    //Create a SqlCommand instance
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);
    //Add the parameter
    command.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = textbox1.Text;

    //Execute the query
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch
    {
        //Handle exception, show message to user...
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.Close(); 
    }
}
```

**Update:**

To execute this code on the click of a button, place the code here (Make sure youi have a button with name `YourButton`):

```
private void YourButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Place above code here
}
```

**Update2:**

You should have a connection string to use in the SqlConnection, this string might look something like:

```
string connectionString = "Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;";
```

Here, you have to replace the values that start with `my` with your own values. More info/examples on connectionstrings for SQL Server:

- [**SQL Server connection strings**](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/)

Comment: save it me from writing..was just finishing

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I would like to learn good habits here so I will try to use the SqlCommand with parameters. How would I execute the query in the button event handler?

Comment: I changed my code already, place it in the event of the button you prefer.

Comment: @Abbas correct me if I am wrong. Position should be `[Position]` in the query.

Comment: connectionString does not exist in the current context apparently. Do I need some new using directives? Also error on ExecuteQuery.

Comment: Thanks - The last thing is just the ExecuteQuery - Error 1 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand' does not contain a definition for 'ExecuteQuery' and no extension method 'ExecuteQuery' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Updated, should have been `ExecuteNonQuery`, my bad.

Comment: Thanks, also I get an error at connection.open() - An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Comment: You should probably open a new question regarding this, including the code and the exception + message that is thrown. This exception is off-topic regarding to your original question. I'll be glad to help you further there.

Answer (score 1):

As makambi already said. You shouldnt do it like that because you are opening doors for SQL injection. Rather use parametrized queries like this:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT employeeID, name, position, hourlyPayRate FROM dbo.employee WHERE name LIKE @name", connection);

cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", textBox1.Text);
connection.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

or use a stored proceedures.

Answer (score 1):

As a minor aside; here's an altenative approach that shows how to do it avoiding the overhead of `DataTable` etc, and with simple but safe and efficient parameterization and materialization:

```
public class Employee {
    public int EmployeeID {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Position {get;set;}
    public decimal HourlyPayRate {get;set;}
}
...
// uses the "dapper" tool to provide the Query<T> extension method;
// freely available from NuGet: PM> Install-Package Dapper
var employees = connection.Query<Employee>(@"
SELECT employeeID, name, position, hourlyPayRate 
FROM dbo.employee 
WHERE name LIKE @pattern",
    new { pattern = "%" + textBox1.Text + "%" }).ToList();

grid.DataSource = employees;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right, you manually build your sql query. It's a bad practice to do it with plain string concatenation because it makes possible SQL injections, instead you should use SqlCommand syntax and just add SqlParameters in it.

```
   using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("connection"))
   {
       var commandText = "SELECT employeeID, name, position, hourlyPayRate FROM dbo.employee WHERE name LIKE @name";

       using (var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(commandText, sqlConnection))
       {
             sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@salary", SqlDbType.Money).Value = textBox1.text;
       }
   }
```

It's not actually tested, and it might not work as it is, but it describes and idea. You just add parameters with sql type you need, please see more examples here:  [When should "SqlDbType" and "size" be used when adding SqlCommand Parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624811/different-ways-of-passing-sqlcommand-parameters)

Comment: I think this should better be a comment

Answer (score 0):

The where clause should be WHERE name LIKE textBox1.text + 'rest of query'

But as makambi mentions, the way your'e building the query open you up to sql injection

Comment: what do you mean by 'rest of query' that would be the end would it not?