# Display same image from database on the next page

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I am working on a website where I am facing a problem. I am a beginner so please don't get angry with me. My question is: I have uploaded an image file into the database and displayed it in the box simultaneously. Now what I want is when I jump to the next page the same picture will appear in the box there so I can do some resizing of it.

What I have done so far is the following piece of code but no success it is giving the error

> Must declare the scalar variable "@id"

I have googled for a solution but there is no solution I've found that works for me. Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

ASPX Part is:

```
<asp:Image ID="image" 
 runat="server" 
 ImageUrl='<%# Eval("image") %>' 
 width="450" />
```

CS Part is:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Tim-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;
                                       Initial Catalog=AP_Data;
                                       Integrated Security=True");
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT image 
                                                     FROM photo 
                                                     WHERE id=@id", 
                                                     con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            DataBind();
        }
```

Comment: You have to add parameters as well

Comment: You need to pass value for `@id`

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624811/different-ways-of-passing-sqlcommand-parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must create a @Id parameter...

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT image FROM photo WHERE id=@id",con);
SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
param.ParameterName = "@id";
param.Value = "Value_Of_parameter"; //Example 1
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
```

Comment: still no success :( 


Line 19:             param.ParameterName = "@id";

Comment: Thank you Sir, after so many efforts and with reference to your idea its working now :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT image FROM photo WHERE id=@id", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", paramVal);
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
```

Hope this helps you!