# Trying to Insert data into tables via Stored Procedure. Keep getting Error converting data type nvarchar to int

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, asp.net-mvc-5

So my issue is when I try to pass data from my view to my controller to input into 4 tables through the use of a stored procedure I get an 'Error converting data type nvarchar to int' sql exception. Three of the tables have foreign keys in the one table, two of those foreign keys populate a drop down list and the last foreign key uploads a file to a directory.

I have tried changing to datatypes for the fields and still get the error. I have also compared the controller code against one that has the same implementation just with one less table, and the code seems fine.

I would like to know what actually causes this error, and how to troubleshoot and solve it.

My View specifically the foreign key portions:

```
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.colourID, "Colour", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.DropDownList("colourID", String.Empty)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.colourID)
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="editor-label">
                    <label> Upload FCC Logo </label>
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Upload, new { type = "file" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Upload)
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.formatID, "formatID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.DropDownList("formatID", String.Empty)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.formatID)
                    </div>
                </div>
```

My Controller's Create Method:

```
 public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.colourID = new SelectList(db.Colours, "colourDesc", "colourDesc");
            ViewBag.logoDocID = new SelectList(db.FCCLogoDocs, "logoDocID", "logoDocTitle");
            ViewBag.formatID = new SelectList(db.Formats, "formatID", "formatName");
            return View();
        }

        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(CreateFCCLogoViewModel createLogo)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var doc = createLogo.Upload;

                var temp = "";
                var temp2 = "";

                if (doc.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    var docName = Path.GetFileName(doc.FileName);
                    var path = Path.Combine("/Content/FCCLogoDocs", docName);
                    temp = Path.Combine("/Content/FCCLogoDocs", docName);
                    temp2 = docName;
                    doc.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(path));
                }
                else
                {
                    temp2 = "No documentation available";
                }
                SqlParameter pName = new SqlParameter("@Name", createLogo.name);
                SqlParameter pDesc = new SqlParameter("@Desc", createLogo.desc);
                SqlParameter pYear = new SqlParameter("@Year", createLogo.year);
                SqlParameter pColourID = new SqlParameter("@ColourID", createLogo.colourID);
                SqlParameter pDocPath = new SqlParameter("@DocPath", temp);
                SqlParameter pDocName = new SqlParameter("@DocName", temp2);
                SqlParameter pFormatID = new SqlParameter("@FormatID", createLogo.formatID);

                db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("spCreateFCCLogo @Name,@Desc, @Year,@ColourID,@DocPath, @DocName, @FormatID",
                                                pName, pDesc, pYear, pColourID, pDocPath, pDocName, pFormatID);

                db.SaveChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            ViewBag.colourID = new SelectList(db.Colours, "colourID", "colourDesc", createLogo.colourID);
            ViewBag.formatID = new SelectList(db.Formats, "formatID", "formatName", createLogo.formatID);
            return View(createLogo);
        }
```

My Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spCreateFCCLogo]
    @Name varchar(300),
    @Desc varchar(300),
    @Year DateTime,
    @ColourID int,
    @FormatID int,
    @DocName varchar(300),
    @DocPath varchar(300)
AS

BEGIN
    DECLARE @DocID int

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[FCCLogoDoc]([logoDocPath],[logoDocTitle])
    VALUES(@DocPath,@DocName)

    SELECT @DocID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[FCCLogo]([name],[desc],[year],[colourID],[logoDocID],[formatID])
    VALUES(@Name,@Desc,@Year,@ColourID,@DocID,@FormatID)


END
```

Comment: You're saying `sp_name @param1, @param3, @param2` - if you're going to do it this way (I suggest adding the parameters by name rather than this way), you need to make sure they're in the same order. Also [stop using the `sp_` prefix](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix).

Comment: @AaronBertrand would the sp_ prefix be possibly causing this issue through ambiguity?

Comment: Either way i changed the name of the stored procedures to remove the sp prefix, now that I know what that can actually cause. The issue still persists. Could the issue be caused by how the controller is accessing the stored procedure, or how the dropdowns are passing data?

Comment: The issue is caused by `sp_procedurename @param1, @param3, @param2` - please compare the order you've listed in the code to the order the parameters are listed in the stored procedure definition. You fix it by either (a) naming the parameters so order is irrelevant (preferred), (b) changing the code to list the parameters in the same order as the procedure, (c) changing the stored procedure to list the parameters in the same order as the code (definitely least preferred).

Comment: @AaronBertrand That solved my issue. Thanks man. Though I did change the order in which the parameters are declared. I unfortunately don't know how to go about naming them so order would be irrelevant, it would be great if you could tell me so that I don't have and issue like this in the future.

Comment: You use a SqlCommand, add the parameters to it, and then just execute it, instead of the redundant way you're doing it with ExecuteSqlCommand. Maybe [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624811/different-ways-of-passing-sqlcommand-parameters) will help (though it is missing the SqlCommand declaration and execution, but it's a start).

Answer (score 0):

Aaron Bertrand answered the question. The issue was the order which the parameters were declared in the stored procedure compared to the code.

Comment: is this ***answer*** ? or maybe comment ? final code working ?