# Linq Stored procedures, send parameter via System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure

Tags: c#, linq

I have a stored procedure and I need to send some parameters, just now I have:

```
readonly efacEntities _db = new efacEntities();
```

This is my model instance

And into my function I have:

```
_db.Database.Connection.Open();

var command = _db.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "dbo.MyStoredProceadure ";
command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

command.Parameters["@step"].Value = "668987";
command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

var test = (command.ExecuteScalar());
```

But I get an error.

Is necessary send the parameter `step` or the parameter is not executing the `command.ExecuteScalar`, how I can send parameters in this query type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to correctly add the parameter to the command object prior to executing it:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@step", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 668987;
```

if @step is an int, or:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@step", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = "668987";
```

if @step is VARCHAR(50)

**EDIT:**

The above statements work provided that the command object is of type `SqlCommand`, which is clearly not the case here!

For a `DbCommand` object we can add a new parameter like this:

```
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter() 
                       { ParameterName = "@step", 
                         SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int, 
                         SqlValue = "66897" 
                       })
```

Comment: Says: `The method add has 1 parameter`, and with this example its sending 2 parameters (key and value)

Comment: @MrMins I don't get it. The lines I have posted are syntactically correct. Are you sure you have this error when exactly either of these lines gets executed?

Comment: The error not are in the executing time, it's before to compile it. That says the debugger

Comment: @MrMins I know the error you get is during compile time. That's way I said the lines are syntactically correct. Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624811/different-ways-of-passing-sqlcommand-parameters

Comment: `command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter()
            {
                ParameterName = "@estado",
                SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int,
                SqlValue = "1"
            });`

Finally, based in your answer, I used the `new SqlParameter()` parameter to add the fields and it's working

Comment: @mrMins I'm glad you've got it right. The version of the "Add"  method you are using takes only one parameter. The overload I am using takes either two or three parameters.