# using placeholder in sql query in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am an ASP.Net developer & using sql server CE 4.0 I want to know how to use place holder for this code, As this query is currently vulnerable to sql injection. Place holder can prevent this but the problem is for example query = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE TITLE = @0" but in my query the value of @0 is dynamically added to query how do i use place holder 
this is the code

```
if (Request["search"] != "" && Request["search"] != null)
    {
        var search = Request["search"].Trim();
        string[] querynew = search.Split(' ');
        var searchquery = "and ";
        foreach (string word in querynew)
        {
            searchquery += "response_table.adtitle LIKE '%" + word + "%' OR ";
        }
        sql += searchquery.Remove(searchquery.Length - 4);
    }
    if (Request["min"] != "" && Request["min"] != null && Request["max"] != null && Request["max"] != "")
    {
        sql = sql + " and (CAST(response_table.price AS Float)) between " + Request["min"].Trim() + " AND " + Request["max"].Trim();
    }
    // 3. the order clause    

    switch (Request["sort"])
    {
        case "recent":
            sql = sql + "ORDER BY response_table.response_ID DESC OFFSET " + offset + " ROWS FETCH NEXT " + pageSize + " ROWS  ONLY";
            break;
        case "hightolow":
            sql = sql + "ORDER BY CAST(response_table.price AS Float) Desc OFFSET " + offset + " ROWS FETCH NEXT " + pageSize + " ROWS  ONLY";
            break;
        case "lowtohigh":
            sql = sql + "ORDER BY CAST(response_table.price AS Float) ASC OFFSET " + offset + " ROWS FETCH NEXT " + pageSize + " ROWS  ONLY";
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    result = db.Query(sql);
```

Thank You

Comment: they're called parameters, not placeholders. Put them on your command object. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624811/different-ways-of-passing-sqlcommand-parameters

Comment: Not to sure if you have used `&&` correctly in your if statements, it should be `||`

Comment: they are correct i need form data not to be null & empty so && condition is correct

Comment: Sorry i didn't knew they are called parameters but please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using parameters (instead of concatenating strings) allows you to optimize performance of your queries.

You can use a [SqlCeCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlcecommand(v=vs.100).aspx). It has a collection of parameters and you can find a sample [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlcecommand.parameters(v=vs.100).aspx) regarding how to use them.