# How to insert latitude and longitude in database from click event?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Using ASP.net and WebForms i am trying to store the user's location (Latitude, Longitude) to a database. This presents the problem:

How can i **get** the user's latitude and longitude into a place where server-side ASP.net code can then save it into a database.

### What have you tried?

I don't care which technology is used; i just need their location. My first attempt was to try to use **Google Maps** in order to access the current location. And while i **can** use javascript in the browser to get ahold of the current location, i cannot figure out how to transfer that information to the server.

Here's the sample code of my first attempt:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head runat="server">
   <title></title>
</head>
<body>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      var long = 0;
      var lat = 0;
      window.onload = function () {
         var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(18.9300, 72.8200),
            zoom: 14,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
         };
         var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
         var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
         var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);
         google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (e) {
            long = e.latLng.lng();
            lat = e.latLng.lat();
            alert("Latitude: " + lat + "\r\nLongitude: " + long);
         });
      }
   </script>

   <div id="dvMap" style="width: 300px; height: 300px">
      <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
   </div>
</body> 
</html>
```

And below is the **.aspx** code-behind file. We save the longitude and latitude to the database during the **Click** event of the button:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //TODO: Ask Stackoverflow how to get these values from browser-land javascript
    Double latitude = 0;
    Double longitude = 0;

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = "@Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True";

    string query1 = "insert into Courses(longi,lati) values (@lati, @longi)";

    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(query1, con);
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lati", latitude);
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@longi", longitude);

    con.Open();
    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

### Location API

Nothing says i need to be using Google Maps. I know that HTML has a Location API accessible somewhere, somehow. Is there an established way that the browser's **Location API** can be used to feed the user's location to the server in ASP.net?

Comment: This shouldn't even compile, `cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@crn" )` ?. You are suppose to add parameters for `@lati, @longi` with actual values.

Comment: This is not mvc, if I'm correct, please remove the `asp.net-mvc` tag to avoid confusions

Comment: sir how i pass value in that prarameter

Comment: You might find useful examples here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624811/when-should-sqldbtype-and-size-be-used-when-adding-sqlcommand-parameters or here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add asp hidden fields, with runat="server" to hold the lat and lng.  When you get the lat and lng in your javascript simply populate the hidden fields with those values. Then you can reference the hidden fields values directly in your OnClick handler.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
   <head id="Head1" runat="server">
   <title></title>
</head>
<body>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       var long = 0;
       var lat = 0;
       window.onload = function () {
           var mapOptions = {
               center: new google.maps.LatLng(18.9300, 72.8200),
               zoom: 14,
               mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
           };
           var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
           var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
           var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);
           google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (e) {
               long = e.latLng.lng();
               lat = e.latLng.lat();
               document.getElementById("lat").value = lat;
               document.getElementById("lng").value = long;
               alert("Latitude: " + lat + "\r\nLongitude: " + long);
           });
       }
   </script>

<form id="myForm" runat="server">
   <div id="dvMap" style="width: 300px; height: 300px">
   </div>
   <asp:HiddenField ID="lat" runat="server" />
   <asp:HiddenField ID="lng" runat="server" />
   <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />

</form>
</body>
```

Code behind:

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //TODO: Ask Stackoverflow how to get these values from browser-land javascript
        Double latitude = Convert.ToDouble(lat.Value);
        Double longitude = Convert.ToDouble(lng.Value);

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = "@Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True";

        string query1 = "insert into Courses(longi,lati) values (@lati, @longi)";

        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(query1, con);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lati", latitude);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@longi", longitude);

        con.Open();
        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

    }
```

Comment: Just had to move hidden fields and button outside of div. I updated code. If you click the map now it will update the hidden fields and display the dialog. Once you click the button, it should insert it into your database.

Comment: What precision is your decimal in the database? You might to replace Convert,ToDouble() with Decimal.Parse(lat) and Decimal.Parse(lng).  Have you stepped through my code in debig mode? Are you getting non-zero values for latitude and longitude variables before you try to insert it into the database?