# .NET DataTable to XML to SQL to DataTable

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, datatable

I'm trying to pass a DataTable between C# and SQL Server both ways. I'm currently using XML to facilitate this, but I'm struggling to deserialize the XML both ways (i.e. to deserialize the C# XML in SQL Server, and to deserialize the SQL Server XML in C#). I'm currently using the following procedure to create the XML in C#:

```
var dt = new DataTable();
//Populate the DataTable...
var set = new DataSet();
set.Tables.Add(dt);
var sb = new StringBuilder();
using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter(sb))
{
  set.WriteXml(stringWriter);
}
string xml = sb.ToString();
```

I'd then like to be able to parse this XML in SQL Server. Is there a way to automatically parse this as a DataTable in SQL Server (using a schema I would suppose)?

Comment: Use [TableAdapter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7zt3ycf2.aspx). The intermediate XML is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Since sql server 2008 you can use table valued parameters to pass data tables [from .net](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163(v=vs.110).aspx) to [sql server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489(v=sql.130).aspx).
You will have to create a user defined table type in the database and pass the parameter as readonly to the stored procedure as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31965233/adding-multiple-parameterized-variables-to-a-database-in-c-sharp/31965525#31965525) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11102358/how-to-pass-an-array-into-a-sql-server-stored-procedure/11105413#11105413).

To pass data tables from sql server to .net you can use .net's `TableAdapter` to execute a select statement and fill a `DataTable` object, as dmonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31942753/calling-a-stored-procedure-results-in-an-incorrectly-empty-datatable/31946745#31946745).