# SQL Server : Select Date from database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, date, select

I have a variable `string session_start_time` which gets result from database and is - 2017-07-15 03:54:37.000

But the following query results in an error:

```
select * 
from surf_ads_views 
where date_time >= " + session_start_time + " 
  and member_id = " + member_id
```

The error is below:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Incorrect syntax near '3'.

I am not able to figure out, why its causing an error

Comment: Learn how to use parameters. Do not concatenate strings to form sql commands. It is an infinite source of problems

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass parameters to SQLCommand?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/293311/).

Comment: yeah as Steve says use parameters and add [ ] around the words which is in DB like name of tables, columns

Answer (score 2):

Your particular issue is that you are injecting the string which needs to be wrapper in single quotes.

`...date_time >='" + session_start_time + "' and ...`
That being said, you should use parameters instead of SQL injection as it will address these types of issues and improve your security.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the property type from String to DateTime, and let the data base manage the type as it is configured, and use stored procedure instead of SQL statements

Create procedure dbo.SelectData
@StartDate DateTime
As
select * from surf_ads_views where date_time = @StartDate