# Formatting a string from a source column in SQL Parameters

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, parameters, sqlcommand

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to format a string from a sourceColumn when adding a parameter to a SqlCommand.

So something like this

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@sdate", SqlDbType.VarChar, 25, "start_date");
```

I don't know how the syntax would be if this would be possible. Something like:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@sdate", SqlDbType.VarChar, 25, string.Format("{0} {1}", "start_date", "12:00 AM"));
```

I'm sure this wouldn't work, because then it would just look for a column name of  "start_date 12:00 AM"

Hopefully it makes sense what I'm trying to do.

Thanks!

Comment: To what are you adding that parameter (a query-based command, executing a sproc, ...)?  I'm guessing it's typed varchar(25) (since that's what you say).  Are you just asking "can I put an expression containing a function like string.Format in as a value for a parameter?"  If so, "yes".  I don't understand your statement that starts "I'm sure this wouldn't work".  Why wouldn't it?  Have you tried?

Comment: This is a column sourced parameter for a SqlAdapter. In the first line of code, it is done properly, with the assumption that the source for the query is a DataTable with a column named "start_date".

In that DataTable, there is no column named "start_date 12:00 AM" which is what it would look for if I were to do it the second way, which would certainly not work.

Comment: Sorry, I got the parameters to Parameters.Add wrong in my head.  Do you want to set the value of "start_date" to "start_date 12:00 AM"?.  Then add the parameter and immediately set the value to your string.Format expression

Comment: I may be misunderstanding your question, but to clarify, I'm trying to add the time component to the *value* that's contained within the start_date column.

For example, if the value was "7/19/2018", I'd want to append the time to become "7/19/2018 12:00 AM"

Comment: Look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/293311/whats-the-best-method-to-pass-parameters-to-sqlcommand

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found an answer to the question, but one solution that I went with was to just format the date before putting it into the DataTable. That way, I can just do a straight insert of the column value as is, and don't need to do any formatting during the insert.