# How to declare scalar variable in parameterized method in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ado.net, sqlclient

I want to get value by using parameterized method, but l am getting this error

> Must declare the scalar variable @Category

I don't know where and how to declare the scalar variable in the code below.

See the code that I have tried

```
[Route("TotalValue")]
[HttpGet]
public decimal TotalValue()
{
    var query = "Select * from OrderDetail where Category = @Category";
    string sqlDataSource = _configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
    decimal total = 0;

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(sqlDataSource))
    {
        con.Open();

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
        {
            using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (dr.Read())
                {
                    total = dr.GetDecimal(0); 
                }
            }
        }

        con.Close();
    }

    return total;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the best method to pass parameters to SQLCommand?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/293311/whats-the-best-method-to-pass-parameters-to-sqlcommand)

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there.

After creating the command, add the @Category parameter to the command's parameters collection:

```
[Route("TotalValue")]
[HttpGet]
public decimal TotalValue()
{
    var query = "Select * from OrderDetail where Category = @Category";
    string sqlDataSource = _configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
    decimal total = 0;

    // If a string (amend for other data type)
    string categoryToFind = "My Category To Search For";

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(sqlDataSource))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Category", categoryToFind);

            using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (dr.Read())
                {
                    total = dr.GetDecimal(0); 
                }
            }
        }
        con.Close();
    }

    return total;
}
```

Comment: But, don't use `AddWithValue`. Much better to use `Add` and then you can inline other important parts, like data type, scale, precision, etc. instead of letting C# guess.

Comment: I am getting this error 'Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.'